# c++ replace what with with on char array(string)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, dynamic, char

I have the task to write a function `char * stringReplace(const char * str, const char * what, const char * with)` which replaces "what" with "with" on a new string with the correct length. So Inside the function I created dynamic array, which the function returns. But my question is how can I delete it after, as If i try to delete it in the main function, after i use it, it says it's undefined. Aren't dynamic arrays without a scope or I'm wrong?
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool areTheSame(const char * str, const char * what, unsigned p)
{


   return areEqual;
}


unsigned howManyTimes(const char * str, const char * what)
{

}


char * stringReplace(const char * str, const char * what, const char * with) 
{

}

int main()
{
   char str[1000];
   char what[1000];
   char with[1000];

   cout << "Enter your string\n";
   cin.getline(str, 1000);

   cout << "\nEnter \"what\" you want to replace\n";
   cin.getline(what, 1000);

   if (strlen(str) < strlen(what))
   {
      cout << "\"What\" contains more characters than the string!\n";
      return 0;
   }

   cout << "\nEnter with what you want to replace it\n";
   cin.getline(with, 1000);

   cout << "\nYour string with replaced words looks like\n";
   cout << stringReplace(str, what, with) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

P.S I deleted parts of the code as I found the answer I wanted and there is still time for the task, and I'm not sure I'm allowed to post my code publicly

Comment: Hmm... I don't see any `delete` in your main function. It should work if you store the result of `stringReplace` in a variable, and `delete` that if it is non-null.

Comment: In main() put the return value of `stringReplace(str, what, with)` in a variable of type char*. Then delete []  after the cout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete it in order to avoid memory leak. You can do something like this:

```
int main()
{
   char str[1000];
   char what[1000];
   char with[1000];
   char *replaced;

   cout << "Enter your string\n";
   cin.getline(str, 1000);

   cout << "\nEnter \"what\" you want to replace\n";
   cin.getline(what, 1000);

   if (strlen(str) < strlen(what))
   {
      cout << "\"What\" contains more characters than the string!\n";
      return 0;
   }

   cout << "\nEnter with what you want to replace it\n";
   cin.getline(with, 1000);

   cout << "\nYour string with replaced words looks like\n";
   replaced = stringReplace(str, what, with);
   cout << replaced << endl;
   delete [] replaced;

   return 0;
}
```

However note that this isn't the best pratice to split allocation/deallocation responsibility.

Comment: This is C++, not C, `replaced` should be declared and initialized at the place it is used first time.

Comment: @Slava And why should it? As far as I know, it's just a matter of readability and used convention.

Comment: because readability is not just. This is one of the most important parts of writing bug free code.

Comment: tnx guys i wrote "char* replaced = stringReplace(str, what, with); delete[] replaced; " and I think it's cool now. I know it's not the best way but the task is given this way and I cant add smth else in the function argument or smth.

Comment: Eventually they will teach you c++ and the pain with dealing with char arrays instead of `std::string` will be done,